# Multiple routes with multiple domains

Tags: symfony, routes

Let's say I've got a website with multiple (sub)domains:

- acme.com (USA)
- acme.nl (Netherlands)
- be.acme.eu (Belgium)
- de.acme.eu (Germany)
- fr.acme.eu (France)
- etc...

I thought this should be very simple to configure, so I made this routing.yml:

```
usa:
    host: "acme.com"
    resource: "@WebsiteBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    defaults:
        country: "en"

netherlands:
    host: "acme.nl"
    resource: "@WebsiteBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    defaults:
        country: "nl"

europe:
    host: "{country}.acme.eu"
    resource: "@WebsiteBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

But if I run `router:debug`, only the last route (in this case  `{country}.acme.eu`) shows up. If I change to order, the last option shows up.

How can I use different (sub)domains for all my countries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because all the routes point to one resource. Every later route will override routes defined before.

But you can use another solution:

```
main_route:
    host: "{country}.acme.{domain}"
    resource: "@WebsiteBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    defaults:
        country: "en"
```

Then check in some listener before controller for valid url and process parameters.

Comment: I think you're right that it isn't possible to have multiple routes/hosts pointed to one resource: http://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/6857

Answer (score 0):

You should use Symfony's [hostname routing](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html).

So your routes would look like:

```
international_homepages:
    path:     /
    host:     "{subdomain}.acme.{extension}"
    defaults:
        _controller: AcmeBundle:Main:defaultHomepage
        subdomain: www
        extension: com
```

Comment: Is your answer in compare with mine have something new?